# System.Data.SQLite не находит на клиентской машине

Tags: c#

В VS2017 в проекте с .NET 4.0 подключил через Nuget пакеты System.Data.SQLite. Прикрутил класс работы с базой в проекте библиотеки dll. На машине разработчика подкидываю в каталог к dll проекта файлы System.Data.SQLite.dll и SQLite.Interop.dll из каталога проекта **\packages\Stub.System.Data.SQLite.Core.NetFramework.1.0.118.0\ и всё работает.
Если копирую на клиентскую машину к dll проекта указанные библиотеки при обращении к классу, который работает с SQLite появляется исключение:
Не удалось загрузить файл или сборку "System.Data.SQLite, Version=1.0.118.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139" либо одну из их зависимостей. Не удается найти указанный файл.
Пробовал разные версии x86 x64 с сайта SQLite - не помогает. Может библиотеки нужно как то регистрировать? Так как dll проекта просто копируется на клиентскую машину.

Comment: А почему такие жесткие требования использовать фреймворк 10-летней давности? А так, найдите саму библиотеку в папке сборки и копируйте вместе с исполняемым файлом.

Answer (score 0):

Решение зависит от версии dll, которые используются, во первых Data.SQLite.dll нужно было скопировать в рабочий каталог .NET используемой программы, а он отличается и может меняться в процессе работы. Метод app.domain.current поможет определить текущий рабочий каталог. Для некоторых операционных систем SQLite.Interop.dll пришлось делить на каталоги x86 и x64. Кратко механизм описан на официальном сайте SQLite.